# is protobuf a runtime or build time dependency

Tags: dependencies, language-agnostic, protocol-buffers, grpc

Something that isn't exactly clear when looking through the documentation and online resources is whether or not protobuf is required at runtime or strictly at build time. is the package only used to generate the client server bindings or is it also used at runtime for encoding/decoding?

if I create a client for a specific architecture in a language like c++ or rust, and someone installs that client on their machine, do they need to have `protobuf` installed locally in order for it to work? I imagine this is more important of a distinction for c++ as this would only matter if dependencies were dynamically linked.

Comment: Yes, I think so though I'm unfamiliar with all the language bindings. `protoc` generates language-specific structs|classes that represent the proto-defined messages but something needs to (un)marshal these onto the wire and (stream) transmit|receive them using HTTP/2.